# How to correct use GLFW3 with code::blocks on ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, glfw

I download GLFW source code. Next correct compile with sudo make install, after that library is installed in /usr/local , now when I create project in code blocks I can include GLFW/glfw3.h, but when I try to complie i have errors [image]

How to correct add this library ?

Comment: you need to link GL also.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I must write this command to terminal: " g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp -lglfw3 -lGL -lX11 -lXi -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXinerama -lXcursor -lrt -lm -pthread" , is any posiibility to automatize linking and compilation with Code::Blocks ?

Answer (score 0):

Just click :

```
Project -> Build Options
```

And then just add liked libs. Of course widouth `-` sign. 
And you must remember that there are Debug Release and both. So you must enter names of those libs in good target.