# glfw3 for code::blocks 16.01 in ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, codeblocks, glfw

I am facing a really for me time-expensive problem. I am new to ubuntu and want to start learning more about opengl by using the glfw. Of course I cannot switch the OS so I will have to stay at ubuntu. I have come so far that I installed the glfw( by following [this](https://github.com/filipwasil/fillwave/issues/58) "tutorial": 2. step by filipwasil), so I have got an include directory in the usr/local dir, aswell as a lib directory. The include directory contains the glfw3.h and the lib directory the libglfw3.a file. If I try to add them to my project in code::blocks it seems like only the include part works, because I can see the functions provided by the glfw while typing, but once I want to compile and run the project, I get an error for each glfw function call: like "not defined reference to e.g. glfwInit". The lib directory also contains a cmake dir, which contains glfwconfig and glfwtarget files, but I really do not know what these files should do. I also noticed the question by [Artur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549485/how-to-correct-use-glfw3-with-codeblocks-on-ubuntu), which is quiet identical, but it does not help me because I want to know which files exactly I have to add in order to get a running window. So may question is: How is it possible to make the code::blocks IDE, actually the gcc compiler, know whats behind the glfw functions?

> Every help will be appreciated. Sorry for my bad english. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add GL, GLEW and glfw in the linker settings. Note the "glfw" in lowercase